# Float right is reversing the order of my nav bar

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a responsive nav bar and when I move my 'work' and 'contact' links to float right, it reverses the order. I tried adding them into a div but when I do that, the link 'work' shows up next to the hamburger menu in mobile view.

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="home.html" class="active">NAME</a>
      <a href="work.html">WORK</a>
      <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

That is currently how it is to the left, but when I add this code to float right is when the reserve order problem happens

```
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {
float: right;
padding-right: 32px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how float:right works. Why don't you float the entire topnav instead?

Comment: When I add it to the .topnav nothing changes, .topnav a currently has a float left, but I need the 2 links 'work, contact' to float right. When I try to target it through .topnav a:not(:first-child) to float right, it reverses the order.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a quick solution (float e.g. a span right, which is containing the left floated elements):

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

span.right {
  float: right;
}

.topnav a:not(:first-child) {
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="home.html" class="active">NAME</a>
      
      <span class="right">
        <a href="work.html">WORK</a>
        <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      </span>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The order is correct when I tried that method, but for some reason when it's on mobile view with the hamburger menu, the link 'work' still appears next to it.

Comment: could you add the new code to your question? With the burger menu?

Comment: Sure I added the javascript for the responsive menu and the stylesheet to the css where I get the icon.